# Building process fails at cmake for PyCarl and asked to recompile with -fPIC

Tags: python, cmake, subprocess

I'm using a docker of ubuntu 19.04 docker to install PyCarl. I have carl and carl-parser (master14 version). However, the 'python setup.py develop' command fails in setup.py with a calledProcessException with exit code 2. The initial command being:

`subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', ext.name] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)`

which boils down to:

```
cmake --build . --target core --config Release -- -j4
```

However, I'm ending up with a CalledProcessError with an exit code of 2.
Any help in suggesting me where the error might be would be of great help.

[image: Please see the bottom of the screenshot for the described error]

Additionally,
It seems that the above error is due to a previous unresolved error as suggested in the comments.

```
root@196abd768845:/pycarl# python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing lib/pycarl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to lib/pycarl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to lib/pycarl.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'lib/pycarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'lib/pycarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Pycarl - Using carl with master14 branch.
Pycarl - Using carl 14.18.10 from /carl/build
Pycarl - carl parser extension from  included.
Pycarl - Support for CLN found and included.
Pycarl - CMake args=['-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/pycarl/lib/pycarl/', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-Dcarl_DIR=/carl/build']
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.a(osdoprnti.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__gmp_allocate_func' can not be used when making ashared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmpxx.a(osfuns.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a(memory.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

The above continues for a lot of variables and finally displays:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a(randmt.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__gmp_free_func' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/core.dir/build.make:142: ../../lib/pycarl/core.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:295: CMakeFiles/core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:307: CMakeFiles/core.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:196: core] Error 2
```

I did try `export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC"` but that did not solve the error.

Addition 2:
Thanks for your input guys. But I can see that both .a and .so are present in the library. So why is it not selecting the shared one instead? Or how can I dynamically link it? I tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: It tells you at the top that linking failed. Apparently the build system doesn’t work correctly for your platform.

Comment: @Darklighter yes I guess the final error is a result of previous unresolved errors but I cannot make much sense of those.

Comment: Well, you did file [an issue](https://github.com/moves-rwth/pycarl/issues/1) . I assume `GMPXX_SHARED` `GMP_SHARED` from [here](https://github.com/smtrat/carl/blob/3c0e0a4d80c64281980afe7c4bacb7bf2b18d622/src/carl/CMakeLists.txt#L14) are not propagated correctly.

Comment: The error message tells that you have **already installed** libraries `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.a` and so. These libraries are static ones (`.a` extension) and most likely haven't been compiled with `-fPIC`. But the project is built with fPIC ([CMakeLists.txt:120](https://github.com/smtrat/carl/blob/3c0e0a4d80c64281980afe7c4bacb7bf2b18d622/CMakeLists.txt#L120) sets it). Message `recompile with -fPIC` says that you need to recompile these libraries with fPIC support (or, simpler, install shared variant of these libraries). It is **not** about compiling the **project** with `fPIC`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev True. I think the idea is that you should link to GMP dynamically if you build a shared object that wants to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for paving for the way [@Tsyparev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) and [@Darklighter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747962/darklighter). I guess I figured it out. 
Carl installed gmp 6.2.1 as it found the default gmp tp be 6.0.0. All I had to do was link up the path (namely, `LD_RUN_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, for the noobs like me) to that folder (which was `carl/build/resources/lib` for me).